# Create a search API using django tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-1.9

I am trying to design an api for search functionality. I want an API for implementing in the reactjs. What i want is /api/v1/rent/search/place="place name" but i am not getting this. What i did was

**api.py**

```
from rentals.models import Rental,Gallery
from django.core.paginator import InvalidPage
from django.conf.urls import *
from tastypie.paginator import Paginator
from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

class SearchResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Rental.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rent'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/search%s$" % (
                    self._meta.resource_name,
                    trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('get_search'),
                name="api_get_search"
            ),
        ]

    def get_search(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        self.is_authenticated(request)
        self.throttle_check(request)

        # Do the query.
        sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Rental).load_all().auto_query(request.GET.get('q', ''))
        paginator = Paginator(sqs, 20)

        try:
            page = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))
        except InvalidPage:
            raise Http404("Sorry, no results on that page.")

        objects = []

        for result in page.object_list:
            bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=result.object, request=request)
            bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)
            objects.append(bundle)

        object_list = {
            'objects': objects,
        }

        self.log_throttled_access(request)
        return self.create_response(request, object_list)
```

**models.py**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    city =  models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("City of the rental space"))
    place =  models.CharField(_("Place"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Place of the rental space"))

class Gallery(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('Rental'), related_name="gallery")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='upload/',null=True)
```

What else do i have to do to achieve the url like api/v1/rent/search/place="place name"(i want to search from the place name) ?

I get following error
[image: traceback]

Comment: i get error when i do this api/v1/searchRent/search/?format=json

Comment: What error do you get? Provide the whole stacktrace if any

Comment: I have attached the error in my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your Python file:

```
from django.core.paginator import InvalidPage
```

Comment: If i do http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rent/q="place name"/?format=json i get an error.

Comment: Try localhost:8000/api/v1/rent/?format=json&q="place%20name"

Comment: when i do localhost:8000/api/v1/rent/?format=json&q="california" i get not only the results of place called california but all the places.

Comment: Try: localhost:8000/api/v1/rent/search/?format=json&q="california"

Comment: "error_message": "page() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given", will get this error if i do such

Comment: There's an error in your code then. Make sure your current code is posted in the question.

Comment: That error implies it happened when you call `paginator.page()`, but it looks like you're using the right number of args. I'd repost that as a new Stack Overflow issue, and include the full traceback.

Comment: I post the traceback here. Will that be a problem?

Comment: I have posted a new question on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674181/page-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given