# page() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-1.9

I am trying to design an api for search functionality. Search is based on place name.What i want is localhost:8000/api/v1/rent/search/?format=json&q="california" but i am getting an error which i have attached below
[image]

```
{
  "error_message": "page() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given",
  "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/tushant/.virtualenvs/rent/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 211, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/tushant/Projects/rentals-v2.1/rentals/api/api.py\", line 102, in get_search\n    page = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))\n\nTypeError: page() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given\n"
}
```

**my code for search api is**

```
    from rentals.models import Rental,Gallery
    from django.core.paginator import InvalidPage
    from django.conf.urls import *
    from tastypie.paginator import Paginator
    from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest
    from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
    from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash
    from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
     class SearchResource(ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            queryset = Rental.objects.all()
            resource_name = 'rent'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/search%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_search'), name="api_get_search"),
        ]

    def get_search(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        self.is_authenticated(request)
        self.throttle_check(request)

        # Do the query.
        sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Rental).load_all().auto_query(request.GET.get('q', ''))
        paginator = Paginator(sqs, 20)

        try:
            page = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))
        except InvalidPage:
            raise Http404("Sorry, no results on that page.")

        objects = []

        for result in page.object_list:
            bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=result.object, request=request)
            bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)
            objects.append(bundle)

        object_list = {
            'objects': objects,
        }

        self.log_throttled_access(request)
        return self.create_response(request, object_list)
```

**my models.py is**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
        city =  models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
            help_text=_("City of the rental space"))
        place =  models.CharField(_("Place"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
            help_text=_("Place of the rental space"))

    class Gallery(models.Model):
        rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('Rental'), related_name="gallery")
        image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='upload/',null=True)
```

What am i missing?

Comment: You should include the full stack trace in your question

Comment: please ad the stacktrace as a text and not an image

Comment: paginator.page() does not take any arguments: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/paginator.html

Comment: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html you can see the documentation , here an argument is passed.

Comment: As a note: I had to change `for result in page.object_list:` to `for result in page['objects']:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a Tastypie Paginator class, which automatically detects the current page based on the requests passed in to it, unlike the Django Paginator class which requires you to pass in the page index.

Here's the code with relevant comments: https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/paginator.py#L26

Try this:

```
    paginator = Paginator(request.GET, sqs, limit=20)

    try:
        page = paginator.page()
    except InvalidPage:
        raise Http404("Sorry, no results on that page.")
```

Comment: This worked. I am getting No module named 'whoosh.codec.whoosh2 error which i will solve it. Thanks for your help.